# Is the set of normal, positive, faithful, linear functionals on a W*-algebra open?

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an infinite-dimensional W*-algebra, that is, an infinite-dimensional $C^{*}$-algebra which is the Banach dual of a Banach space $\mathcal{A}_{*}$ (equivalently, $\mathcal{A}$ is an abstract von Neumann algebra).

Consider the so-called normal positive, linear functionals on $\mathcal{A}$.
According to the general theory of W*-algebras, these are all those positive linear functionals in the dual space $\mathcal{A}^{*}$ that are in the image $i(\mathcal{A}_{*})\subset\mathcal{A}^{*}$ of $\mathcal{A}_{*}$ in its bidual $(\mathcal{A}_{*})^{**}=\mathcal{A}^{*}$.

Now, consider the set $\mathcal{P}$ composed of all those normal,positive, linear functionals on $\mathcal{A}$ that are faithful (assuming, of course, that  $\mathcal{A}$ admits normal, positive, linear functionals that are normal), that is, $\omega\in\mathcal{P}$ is such that $\omega(\mathbf{a}\mathbf{a}^{\dagger})=0$ for some $\mathbf{a}\in\mathcal{A}$ implies $\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{0}$.

Is the set $\mathcal{P}$ open in $\mathcal{A}^{*}$ and/or $\mathcal{A}_{*}$?

Comment: In what topology?

Comment: I am interested mainly in the Banach space topology of $\mathcal{A}^{*}$ or of $\mathcal{A}_{*}$.

Comment: Ok, that makes things a bit unnatural to me, because the set of normal, positive, linear functionals is not open in the norm topology.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this? Also, what is the natural situation you would consider? I apologize if I am asking for trivial things, but I am a physicist who is (slowly) trying to understand the mathematics of $W^*$-algebras ($C^*$-algebras).

Comment: Dont'apologize, your question is very good. It's just that the usual thing in these contexts is to use the weak$^*$-topology (but I said "usual", there's nothing wrong with using the norm topology). The reason for my comment was that you can take a normal functional $\varphi$ and a non-normal one $\psi$, and then $\phi+\tfrac1n\,\psi\to\phi$ in norm, and the elements in the sequence will be non-normal.

Comment: Thank you very much (for the moral support and) for the nice and simple example. So, the set $\mathcal{P}$ is not open in the norm topology of $\mathcal{A}^{*}$, however, your example relies on the choice of a non-normal state, so, what happens with respect to the norm topology of $\mathcal{A}_{*}$? Moreover, what can be said if we consider the weak* topology?

Comment: I have written the (little) I have to say in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are considering the weak$^*$-topology, the answer is "no". Take $\varphi$ be a faithful, normal, state, and $\{p_j\}$ and increasing net of projections with $p_j\nearrow 1$. Then the net $\{\varphi(p_j\cdot )\}_j$ converges weak$^*$ (i.e., pointwise) to $\varphi$. None of the functionals $\varphi(p_j\cdot)$ is faithful. We can also make the approximating functionals non-normal by using the trick I mention below.

When you consider the norm topology, normal functionals are norm-limits of non-normal ones: take $\varphi$ normal, $\psi$ non-normal, and form the sequence $\varphi+\tfrac1n\,\psi$.

And regarding things purely in the predual. Let $\mathcal A=B(H)$ with $H$ separable. Then $\mathcal A_*$ is $L^1(H)$, the trace-class operators. Fix an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$.  Let $\varphi\in L^1(H)$ be 
$$
\varphi = \sum_n\frac1{n^2}\,\langle \cdot,e_n\rangle\,e_n.
$$ 
We may see it as a linear functional
$$
\varphi(T)=\sum_n \frac1{n^2}\,\langle Te_n,e_n\rangle. 
$$
Then $\varphi$ is linear, positive, faithful. Let $\varphi_m\in L^1(T)$ be given by 
$$
\varphi_m(T)=\sum_{n\leq m}\frac1{n^2}\,\langle Te_n,e_n\rangle. 
$$
Then $\varphi_m\to\varphi$ in norm (the trace-norm, which is the norm in the predual), and $\varphi_m$ is not faithful for any $m$.

Comment: Very nice answer. However, I am still curious about what happen when we forget about the canonical immersion of $\mathcal{A}_{*}$ in $\mathcal{A}^{*}$ and simply consider only the norm topology on $\mathcal{A}_{*}$. In this case, the trick you mention for constructing a sequence of non-normal, faithful, positive linear functionals converging to a given normal, faithful, positive linear functional does not work because we are not "allowed" to consider non-normal states.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Very good!! I wish I could accept and upvote your answer multiple times.

Comment: No need. Thanks! :D